# How to mount sda hard drive

Tags: linux

We are trying to take a backup from one of the hard drive, it has 4 TB, Previously it was configured in raid. I found this using blkid command.

blkid
/dev/sda TYPE="isw_raid_member"

I am not able to mount this hard drive from ubuntu live os.

fdisk -l

It shows: Disk /dev/sda 3.7 TB.

Partitions are not detecting. Please let me know, how to i mount the hard disk sda in other machine, then only i can take all my backup's.

Comment: May I please ask how your RAID was set up? A) Which software was used to create the array? B) Is there a RAID controller in the source system, and if so, which? C) Did you use the RAID software to remove the drive from the array,, or did you just shut the system down and pull the drive? D) What filesystem type does Mount Manager show? http://www.ubuntugeek.com/mount-manager-user-friendly-management-of-disks-and-partitions.html  Please click [edit] to put your additional information into your question; please do not reply in a Comment, as Comments can get lost.

Answer (score 2):

`isw` refers to **I**ntel **S**oft**w**are RAID. In Linux, it can be used with the `dmraid` utility. (2023 update: Apparently modern enough versions of `mdadm` now handle this format too, which might be a better idea than relying on aging `dmraid`, depending on the age of your distribution, of course.)

To list the software RAID configuration detected on the disk, run this command:

```
sudo dmraid -r
```

Even if the RAID set is a simple RAID 1 mirror, the set itself may include multiple partitions, which might explain the partitions are not accessible until the RAID set is activated.

To try and activate the RAID set on that disk, try this command:

```
sudo dmraid -ay
```

If it's successful, one or more `/dev/dm-*` device nodes should appear on your system, which you could then investigate further, e.g. with this command:

```
sudo file -s /dev/dm-*
```

If the `file`  command reports that a `/dev/dm-*` device contains a `DOS/MBR boot sector; partition ...`, then it is partitioned and you might want to continue with `sudo fdisk -l /dev/dm-<that particular device>` to view the partition table, and `losetup -P /dev/loop0 /dev/dm-<that particular device>` to make the partitions accessible as `/dev/loop0pN` devices.

But if the word `partition`  does not appear, then that `/dev/dm-*`  device is probably directly mountable as a filesystem, and the rest of the `file` command output might tell you the filesystem type.

Answer (score -1):

If no better answer presents itself, you could backup the entire drive image to another drive of the same size or larger with [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/). Create a [LiveUSB with Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) and choose drive-drive after rebooting with that LiveUSB. []